# Scandit Barcode Scanner iOS Crash

Tags: ios, crash, barcode, qr-code

I installed the SDK (2.2.7) and included all the frameworks within the xCode (4.6.2) project. Whenever I try to scan code it crashes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

the getter for scan view

```
- (ScanditSDKBarcodePicker *)scanPicker
{
    if (!_scanPicker)
    {
        _scanPicker = [[ScanditSDKBarcodePicker alloc] initWithAppKey: SCANDIT_APP_KEY];
        UIBarButtonItem *guestButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"List" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(choseFromList:)];
        _scanPicker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = guestButton;
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelPicker:)];
        _scanPicker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
        _scanPicker.overlayController.delegate = self;
        [_scanPicker startScanning];
    }
    return _scanPicker;
}
```

the code presenting it

```
- (void)presentScanditViewController
{
    UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.scanPicker];
    [self presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I checked the app keys also, does anyone have the same problem??

Comment: Whenever you post a question about a crash there are two things required - 1) The complete error message, 2) The relevant part of the stack trace or a reference to the actual code that crashes.

Comment: We will probably need a full stack trace to help you out. You can try adding a exception break point, http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: yes its already have bp on all exceptions, but it wouldn't describe the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poor support and documentation SDK, swapping to ZBar

Answer (score 0):

I too occasionally see this error from Scandit but it's a tiny fraction of all the scans per day.

I implemented it using the documentation on the Scandit site [Scandit iOS SDK Implementation Documentation](http://www.scandit.com/support/getting-started-with-scandit-sdk-for-ios/)

I started out with ZBar but the Scandit code works **much** better than ZBar especially on fixed focus cameras (iPod Touch 4th Gen).

Here's my code to alloc and present the scanner

```
- (IBAction)scanImage:(id)sender
{
picker = [[ScanditSDKBarcodePicker alloc] initWithAppKey:scanditAPIKey];
picker.overlayController.delegate = self;
[picker startScanning];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```